# OpenCV blob tracking on low resolution image in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-c++, opencv, kinect-sdk

I'm using the Kinect SDK in C++ to generate an image of points near a plane in space, with the goal of using them as touches. I've attached a 3x scale image of the result of that process, so thats all gravy.

> [image: Example image of touches]

My question is how best to use OpenCV to generate blobs frame to frame from this image (and images like it) to use for touches. Heres what I've tried in my ProcessDepth callback, where img is a monochrome cv::Mat of the touch image, and out is an empty cv::Mat.

```
    cv::Canny(img,out,100,200,3);
    cv::findContours(out,contours,cv::RETR_TREE,cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,cv::Point(0,0));

    mu.resize(contours.size());
    mc.resize(contours.size());

    for(int i = 0; i<contours.size();i++){
        mu[i] = cv::moments(contours[i],true);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<contours.size();i++){
        mc[i] = cv::Point2f(mu[i].m10/mu[i].m00, mu[i].m01/mu[i].m00);
    }
```

(I'd post more code, but VMWare is being bad about letting me copy paste out of it, if you want more, just ask.)

At which point I think I should get center of masses for blobs for a frame, in practice though, its not there. I get either errors when contour.size() returns greater than 0, or with a bit of tinkering, I get moments that seem really weird, containing large negative numbers say. So my questions are as follows:

- Does anyone have recommendations on how to turn the image below into blob data with a good result, so far as flags in findContours are concerned?
- Do I even need to bother with Cranny or threshold since I have a monochrome image already, and if Cranny, is the kernal of 3 too large for the number of pixels I'm dealing with?
- Will Find contours work on images of this size? (160 ish by 90 ish, though thats fairly arbitrary. Smallish more generally.)
- Are the OpenCV functions async? I get lots of invalid address errors if my images and the contour vector don't exist as properties on the application class. (I'm the first to admit I'm not a particularly talented C++ Programmer.)
- Is there a way simpler way to go from image to series of points corresponding to touches from image?

For reference, I'm cribbing on some examples in my OpenCV download, and [this example](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/moments/moments.html).

Let me know if you need some other information to better answer, and I'll try to provide it, thanks!